# Convert VarChar to Float with different culture format

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, culture, dataformat

From different external sources I get data where some numbers are in a NVarChar field. Until now I used a REPLACE with a CAST to ensure that numbers with a "," where cast the right way. Like this:

```
select cast(replace('12,5',',','.') as float)
select cast(replace('12.5',',','.') as float)
```

This has worked just fine, but now I get data where there is also a thousand separator in. Like this:

```
select cast(replace('2.012,5',',','.') as float)
select cast(replace('2,012.5',',','.') as float)
```

It' broken.
Is there a way to detect which data format is used in a NVarChar with a number?

I have tried to use TRY_PARSE with a culture parameter, it works well if there is a thousand separator but not without:

```
SELECT @Fuelunits = 
CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(TRY_PARSE(@Hoeveelheid AS decimal(9,2) USING 'nl-NL')) = 1 
THEN CAST(TRY_PARSE(@Hoeveelheid AS decimal(9,2) USING 'nl-NL') AS FLOAT)
ELSE CAST(TRY_PARSE(@Hoeveelheid AS decimal(9,2) USING 'en-US') AS FLOAT)
END
```

The problem is that I have to use this in an UPDATE and that that the data format can differ in the same table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tell us what format you are actually looking for here.  It appears that you are going back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CHARINDEX()` to work out what separators are present and where they are in the string along with a `CASE` expression to handle different cases before you `REPLACE` and `CAST` to `FLOAT`:

```
CREATE TABLE #vals (val NVARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #vals
(
    val
)
VALUES 
(N'2.012,5'),
(N'2,012.5');

SELECT CAST(CASE
                -- is there a '.' in a position before a ','?
                WHEN CHARINDEX('.', val) < CHARINDEX(',', val) THEN
                    -- yes - remove the '.' and replace the ',' with '.'
                    REPLACE(REPLACE(val, '.', ''), ',', '.')
                ELSE
                    -- no - just remove the ','
                    REPLACE(v.val, ',', '')
            END AS FLOAT)
FROM #vals AS v;

DROP TABLE #vals;
```

**References:**

[CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql)

> Searches an expression for another expression and returns its starting position if found.

Comment: Thanks Tanner
I used your solution. I don't know why I didn't see this option my self, maybe I was so concentrated to look for a function with some kind of culture setting.

Comment: I think in general there is no solution. For example, if storing 3 places of decimals, how does one distinguish between 1,234 and 1.234 if multiple cultures are present?